# how to get specific data from inspect console with subcategories

Tags: javascript, html, console.log

I am trying to print the console log of a variable "e". here is the console result:

```
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: 'Enter', code: 'Enter', location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
currentTarget: null
key: "Enter"
keyCode: 13
sourceCapabilities: 
srcElement: textarea.w-full.h-full.border-none.focus:border-green-300.focus:ring.focus:ring-green-200
```

here is the console reuslt image:
[image]
e.keyCode can help me to get the keycode information of e, I wanna get `textarea.w-full.h-full.border-none.focus:border-green-300.focus:ring.focus:ring-green-200" information`, but `e.srcElement` cannot help me to get that. Can you please help me to resolve this problem? thanks!

Comment: Of interest here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/125981

Comment: Why isn't `e.srcElement` working? What does it give back to you instead other than the element that's being specified?

Comment: @NickParsons I tried to call e.srcElement and the console result is empty

Comment: Some actual code we might help fix that is doing the logging might help us help you better here.

Comment: @NickParsons it's because that srcElement has subcategories

Comment: @RA.IBOY Thanks, not sure what you mean by subcategories, but as Mark suggested, creating a [mre] would help us see the issue more clearly I think. (side note, `.srcElement` is deprecated, you should instead use `.target` instead)

Comment: Keep in mind that just typing in the console you must use a breakpoint to stop code execution when the `e` object is available. Otherwise javascript tries to find an object e in the global space and because that doesn't exist will print nothing. You can just `console.log(e.srcElement);` have you tried that? srcElement is a HTMLelement, the text you see is just the text-representation of the tag and classes, but it has more properties. Just click the error left of it like you see it in your screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to get class list of an element?

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log([e.target.tagName.toLowerCase(), ...e.target.classList].join('.'))
})
```

```css
.here {
  background: red;
  width: 80vh;
  height: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="some classes here">click me</div>
```

Comment: thanks! and I found that I can get the info from e.target